# AntD table - change cell color on mouse hover

Tags: reactjs, hover, antd

I'm trying to change background color of the cell in antD table using onCell property and onMouseOver function, but without success.

```
onCell: (record, rowIndex) => {
  return {
    onMouseOver: () => {
      console.log("record, row", record, rowIndex);
      return {
        props: {
          style: { background: "yellow", fontWeight: "bold" }
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Working sandbox example:
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-cell-color-onhower-3ju221?file=/demo.tsx)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to add a custom background on hover to the cells of a certain column, perhaps a simple solution would be adding this as a custom class with `onCell`.

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-cell-color-hover-ll0444?file=/index.css)

```
onCell: (record, rowIndex) => {
  return {
    className: "custom",
  };
};
```

In CSS, define `:hover` styles with a higher specificity so that it overrides default style for selected cells:

```
.ant-table-cell.ant-table-cell-row-hover.custom:hover {
  background-color: hotpink;
  color: white;
}
```